# Is there a way to use Dragon Naturally Speaking in latex?

Tags: editors, accessibility

I downloaded my latex IDE and compiler from here: http://www.miktex.org/ (The windows 64 bit version) and I cant seem to get dragon to connect to it.

Comment: Welcome to the site! I think that, with the correct tags, and a few more details, this could be a very useful question. I think the `accessibility` tag needs to be on here, together with specifics related to your question; to help with this, are you wanting Dragon to interact with MiKTeX, your editor, both, or other? Please provide as much detail as you can :)

Comment: I'm inclined to vote to close as a duplicate if the following question is in fact a duplicate. If your issue is simply with Dragon configuration itself, then the question may be off topic.  [How can I use Dragon NaturallySpeaking to write LaTeX math formulas by voice efficiently?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/145367/how-can-i-use-dragon-naturallyspeaking-to-write-latex-math-formulas-by-voice-eff)